# Initializing array: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, short

So, I am having this bizarre error while initializing an array. What happens, is that I create an array, and it will throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`. As you can see on the second line, I do it correctly (In this text example, `data.length / 4` equals 1):

```
short[] data = ByteToShort(Gdx.files.internal(file).readBytes());
O[ID].code.MapFile = new short[data.length / 4][4];
```

And this is what `O[ID].code.MapFile` looks like:

```
public short[][] MapFile;
```

And in case you need it, here is the stack dump:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.GS.SE.SonicEngine.LoadMappings(SonicEngine.java:288)
    at com.GS.SE.obj.ObjSonic.init(ObjSonic.java:47)
    at com.GS.SE.obj.Obj.<init>(Obj.java:8)
    at com.GS.SE.SonicEngine.create(SonicEngine.java:41)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

I am completely stuck with this, it seems there no way to go around this or anything. Any help would be appreciated! If you need more info, comment below and I'll add.

EDIT: As commenters asked, the variables `O[ID]` and `O[ID].code` are NOT null.

EDIT 2: Even AFTER initializing `O[ID].code.MapFile` it WILL cause `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

EDIT 3: I figured out the issue. And it was something I didnt think could matter. As I run objects code threaded, it gets reference a lot there, and for some weird reason, I could not access any of the data from the init code which was ran on the main thread, however making the init code run on the object code thread, it made it work perfectly. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: To which line does `SonicEngine.java:288` refer?

Comment: "As you can see on the second line, I do it correctly". With that I meant the line: `O[ID].code.MapFile = new short[data.length / 4][4];`

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my question... do you know what's on line 288 of `SonicEngine.java`?

Comment: It isn't clear what is null from just these two lines, so I would suggest checking the variables in a debugger or print them out to check if they are null. Things to print would be O[ID], O[ID].code, and data.

Comment: So if you are sure O[ID], O[ID].code are not null (as per your edit), then data is probably null.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and code, I assume that this

```
O[ID].code.MapFile = new short[data.length / 4][4];
```

is throwing your `NullPointerException`. There are two reasons it might, `O[ID]` is `null`. You didn't tell us what `O` is. It's also possible that the `code` field is `null`. Let's check,

```
if (O[ID] != null) {
  if (O[ID].code != null) {
    O[ID].code.MapFile = new short[data.length / 4][4];
  } else {
    System.out.println("O[ID].code == null");
  }
} else {
  System.out.println("O[ID] == null");
}
```

One possible solution might be

```
if (O[ID].code == null) {
  O[ID].code = new Code(); // <-- you didn't tell us.
}
// Then you could
O[ID].code.MapFile = new short[data.length / 4][4];
```

Comment: It is actually not a null, it is defined earlier on the program (and the thing is actually running the code): `O[0] = new Obj(new ObjSonic(), 0);` I also have made 100% sure it will work properly and not cause issues. Also the ID in case is 0

Comment: @GreenSnake Try my code above, it won't throw `NullPointerException` (unless of course it's `data` that is null). Then consider (again) what might be `null` when you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I tested whether `O[ID].code` is null or not, and as I suspected, it turns it is not

Comment: @GreenSnake What is line 288 of SonicEngine.java? The only other possibility is `data` being `null`.

Comment: `O[ID].code.MapFile = new short[data.length / 4][4];` And also `data` is not null.